# Making Struct object issue

Tags: c, struct

```
struct ttype {
    int arity;
    char* items[MAX_ARITY];
};

typedef struct ttype* ntuple;

int main() {
   ntuple obj;
   put(0, "zubair", obj);
}
```

During compilation it's giving me error that uninitialized local variable 'obj' used.

Comment: "*giving me error that uninitialized local variable 'obj' used*". Local variables are not automatically initialised to anything. You never set `obj` so it is not initialised and can contain any garbage value. Which is exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: yes but If I wrote
 obj->arity = 0;
than the same error comes up.

Comment: `obj->arity` is derefencing `obj`. `obj` is uninitalised. So that changes nothing. The compiler message still applies.

Comment: You should not use `typedef` for this. Just use `struct ttype *` as the type and don't hide information from yourself.

Comment: Try to explain what memory `obj` is pointing to.

Comment: The compiler is correct.  Your code is buggy and makes no sense.  Trying to use the value of `obj` before assigning to it is a bug.  That includes passing it as an argument to a function, dereferncing it as a pointer (e.g. your `obj->arity = 0;` example), etc.  The all constitute uses of the *value* of `obj`, which is meaningless until you actually *give it a value*.  A good C tutorial would probably help.  There seems to be no understanding of pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

Your issue here is your typedef `typedef struct ttype* ntuple;`

Due to this, your line with

```c
   ntuple obj;
```

will be "converted" to

```c
    struct ttype * obj;
```

So `obj` is actually a pointer which points to a random address in your memory since you don't initialize it.

## Solutions

1. Remove the typedef.

As @Cheatah already said: The typedef seems to be unnecessary and hides the information that `ntuple` is actually a pointer and not a struct.

So you'd end with the following code:

```c
struct ttype {
    int arity;
    char* items[MAX_ARITY];
};

int main() {
   struct ttype obj;
   put(0, "zubair", &obj);
}
```

#### Note

I don't know how the `put` function is implemented but I suppose that the third parameter should be a reference to the `ttype` struct. If that's not the case, please adjust it.

2. Keep your typedef and allocate some memory

If you really want to keep your typedef, then let your pointer point to some valid memory space:

```c
struct ttype {
    int arity;
    char* items[MAX_ARITY];
};

typedef struct ttype* ntuple;

int main() {
   ntuple obj = malloc(sizeof(struct ttype));
   put(0, "zubair", obj);

   // don't forget to free this dude!
   free(obj);
}
```

I'd recommend to rename your typedef if you *really* need it... for example to `ttype_ptr`.

Comment: Without the typedef, the line `ttype obj` is a compiler error.  It shuld be `struct ttype obj`.

Comment: oh yes, sorry! I forgot to add it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks brother. Your answering is what I need. Thanks a lot @TornaxO7.

Comment: Could you please mark this question as answered please?